# Copied ElasticSearch installation from one server to another, java client no longer works

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am migrating an ElasticSearch index from one server to another. I simply copied the entire installation from one server to the other and then changed the cluster name, node name, and ip address. I am able to start up the new installation fine and it sees the indexes. I am able to query the indexes using curl and get results.

But I am not able to use the java client to query the new machine. I always get this error:

Exception in thread "main" org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: []

I have tried changing the node and cluster name and commenting them out and every combination I can think of. The code is exactly the same java side and I am just changing the ip address of the new server. I am able to telnet to port 9300 on that server so it doesn't seem to be a networking issue.

What am I missing?

Comment: The installation I copied was a 2 node cluster if that helps. I had discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts set on the other server as well as

discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false

And I have removed those lines on the new server, and then tried putting them back in with what I thought was appropriate data, but no luck.

Comment: Also, the original server is on ubuntu 13.10 and the new server is 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

It's tricky to do remote debugging like this over Stack Overflow. But the only other thing that comes to mind would be to double check that you're using the same version of Java (the *exact* same) on the client and server sides.

Comment: I wasn't using the same jvm, but I just switched to using the same one and it is still having issues.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it was a pretty dumb problem. There was a zombie process running on port 9300 and ElasticSearch was failing gracefully by rolling over to port 9301...